Intuition behind taking limits in an inequality
I just came across a situation where $\mathbb{H}$ is a real Hilbert space and $\lbrace x_n \rbrace $ is a sequence in $\mathbb{H}$ that converges to some $\overline{x}$. Also, the sequence satisfies the inequality $\langle f(x_n),y-x_n \rangle \geq{0}$, for all $y\in{C}$, where $C$ is a nonempty, closed and convex subset of $\mathbb{H}$. Clearly, we can take the limit in the above inequality such that $\langle f(\overline{x}),y-\overline{x} \rangle \geq{0}$ is true, for all $y\in{C}$. My question is why is this still true for all $y\in{C}$, after taking the limits?
edit: Thanks to Euclid for the reminder that $f$ is a continuous function.

What you have written is true if $f$ is a continuous function. The reason is that if it were false in the limit, then there would exist a certain $x_n$ ($n$ is arbitrarily large so that $x_n$ is arbitrarily close to $\bar x$) where it is false at that $x_n$ as well. Try to transform this intuition into a mathematically rigorous argument by $\epsilon, \delta$ arguments.

Thanks for pointing out the mistake, My main question is why the inequality is still true for all $y\in{C}$?

There is the following common method of proving statements like $\forall y \in C$. You fix an arbitrary $y' \in C$, and prove that the statement holds for $y'$. Then, this actually implies that the statement is true for all $y \in C$, because the $y'$ we fixed in the beginning was an arbitrary element of $C$. In the case of your problem, I believe that the statement is true for each $y' \in C$ independent of all the other other $y \in C \setminus {y'}$. In other words, while proving the statement for a particular $y'\in C$, you won't use the property holding true for other $y$'s.

That $f(x_n) \to f(\bar x)$ follows from the continuity of $f$. That $y - x_n \to y - \bar x$ follows from the continuity of vector subtraction, that $\langle u_n, v_n\rangle \to \langle u, \langle v$ when $u_n \to u, v_n \to v$ follows from the continuity of the inner product. Putting these together gives the result. Are you unsure about one or more of the pieces, or are you having trouble with the concept of $\forall y\in C$ as Euclid suggests?
